# grep command where value contains spaces

Tags: grep

I have a file mail.txt with the following contents:

```
John Doe john.doe@gmail.com
Mary Doe mary.doe@gmail.com
```

if I type the command in the console :

```
grep -ia 'John Doe' mail.txt
```

I receive a result, but if I want to write it in a script, for example:

```
var="'John Doe'"
mail=mail.txt
result="`grep -ia $var $mail`"
```

I receive the error: `grep: Doe': No such file or directory`. How can this be solved?

Comment: Try wrapping the `$var` in double-quotes: `grep -ia "$var" $mail`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use double quotes to assign the variable.
So you can use double quotes again when defining the command.
could look like this:

```
var="John Doe"
mail=mail.txt
grep -ia "$var" $mail
```

or

```
var="John Doe"
mail=mail.txt
result=`grep -ia "$var" $mail`
echo $result
```